# Powershell date GUI strange behavior

Tags: powershell

When I run this code, you'll see that the first write host will show today's date, but the last 2 will show the default date. Does anyone know why?

The code came from Microsoft, so I'm confused as to why it won't work?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730942.aspx

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

[DateTime] $dtmDate = New-Object DateTime;
[string] $dt = "";
$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date, then press the enter key" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(350,190) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True


$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate = $objCalendar.SelectionStart
            #$dt = $objCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
            Write-Host $dtmDate;
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
if ($dtmDate)
    {
        Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$dtmDate` to `$global:dtmDate`.

The reason is you are assigning the value when the event is triggered so its declared and initialized only locally. Out of the event the variable is only declared. By using `$global` you are changing the scope if the variable to all script.

Btw. never trust Microsoft documentation